# Changing the Style of Braces in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently started to use Android Studio. It uses this style of braces by default:

```
public void scanFile(String filePath) {

}
```

The code I need to submit requires to be styled as follows:

```
public void scanFile(String filePath) 
{

}
```

Where can I find a setting for this?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You need to change the code style in `Project Settings`

```
File -> Settings -> (Project Settings) -> Code Style -> Java -> Wrapping and Brances
```

Change the `Braces Placement` for `Class` and `Method` declaration to `Next Line`

(Or, on a Mac, do the same thing in `Preferences`)

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly for me. Thanks for the screenshot.

Comment: @Libin can you please also help me with this? I'm trying to make it stop forcing me to put braces when there is a single line of code. Each time I use "if (...) Y" , it becomes "if (...) {Y} ", even if "Y" is a single command. I've tried setting "do not force" for the "force braces" value of "if() statement" , but it didn't do anything...

Comment: i want the same setting to apply to any project i open. Not just for one project.

Comment: This is great for new code, but how would you reformat it when selecting already written code (in the old style)?

Comment: @user1147688 Then use Code -> Reformat Code afterwards

Answer (score 10):

This one worked for me in Android Studio 3.0 Beta 7

[image: change braces placement in Android Studio 3]